# Python 3 matplotlib does not support generators as input

Tags: python, dictionary, matplotlib, plot, generator

I am fairly new to Python and it took me hours to figure out what I can do with no success. I am trying an example in plotting from https://jupyter.brynmawr.edu/services/public/dblank/jupyter.cs/FLAIRS-2015/TSPv3.ipynb#Python-and-iPython-Notebook:-Preliminaries. In the section on "Plotting Tours", as labeled as cell 15,16,17,18 and maybe more. The function for plot_tour and plot_lines are using map() and I read that in Python 3 it's a generator instead of a list. This made it confusing so is there any way around this to output the plot? which possibly not using map(). Thank you so much in advance.

**First plot code:**

```
def plot_tour(tour): 
    "Plot the cities as circles and the tour as lines between them."
    plot_lines(list(tour) + [tour[0]])
    
def plot_lines(points, style='bo-'):
    "Plot lines to connect a series of points."
    plt.plot(map(X, points), map(Y, points), style)
    plt.axis('scaled'); plt.axis('off')
plot_tour(alltours_tsp(Cities(8)))
```

**This is the error im getting:**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [18], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 plot_tour(alltours_tsp(Cities(8)))

Input In [17], in plot_tour(tour)
      1 def plot_tour(tour): 
      2     "Plot the cities as circles and the tour as lines between them."
----> 3     plot_lines(list(tour) + [tour[0]])

Input In [17], in plot_lines(points, style)
      5 def plot_lines(points, style='bo-'):
      6     "Plot lines to connect a series of points."
----> 7     plt.plot(map(X, points), map(Y, points), style)
      8     plt.axis('scaled'); plt.axis('off')

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py:2757, in plot(scalex, scaley, data, *args, **kwargs)
   2755 @_copy_docstring_and_deprecators(Axes.plot)
   2756 def plot(*args, scalex=True, scaley=True, data=None, **kwargs):
-> 2757     return gca().plot(
   2758         *args, scalex=scalex, scaley=scaley,
   2759         **({"data": data} if data is not None else {}), **kwargs)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py:1632, in Axes.plot(self, scalex, scaley, data, *args, **kwargs)
   1390 """
   1391 Plot y versus x as lines and/or markers.
   1392 
   (...)
   1629 (``'green'``) or hex strings (``'#008000'``).
   1630 """
   1631 kwargs = cbook.normalize_kwargs(kwargs, mlines.Line2D)
-> 1632 lines = [*self._get_lines(*args, data=data, **kwargs)]
   1633 for line in lines:
   1634     self.add_line(line)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py:312, in _process_plot_var_args.__call__(self, data, *args, **kwargs)
    310     this += args[0],
    311     args = args[1:]
--> 312 yield from self._plot_args(this, kwargs)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py:493, in _process_plot_var_args._plot_args(self, tup, kwargs, return_kwargs)
    490     x, y = index_of(xy[-1])
    492 if self.axes.xaxis is not None:
--> 493     self.axes.xaxis.update_units(x)
    494 if self.axes.yaxis is not None:
    495     self.axes.yaxis.update_units(y)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py:1443, in Axis.update_units(self, data)
   1437 def update_units(self, data):
   1438     """
   1439     Introspect *data* for units converter and update the
   1440     axis.converter instance if necessary. Return *True*
   1441     if *data* is registered for unit conversion.
   1442     """
-> 1443     converter = munits.registry.get_converter(data)
   1444     if converter is None:
   1445         return False

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\units.py:206, in Registry.get_converter(self, x)
    202 else:
    203     # ... and avoid infinite recursion for pathological iterables for
    204     # which indexing returns instances of the same iterable class.
    205     if type(first) is not type(x):
--> 206         return self.get_converter(first)
    207 return None

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\units.py:199, in Registry.get_converter(self, x)
    197         pass
    198 try:  # If cache lookup fails, look up based on first element...
--> 199     first = cbook.safe_first_element(x)
    200 except (TypeError, StopIteration):
    201     pass

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py:1678, in safe_first_element(obj)
   1676     except TypeError:
   1677         pass
-> 1678     raise RuntimeError("matplotlib does not support generators "
   1679                        "as input")
   1680 return next(iter(obj))

RuntimeError: matplotlib does not support generators as input
```

**Next plot code:**

```
def plot_tsp(algorithm, cities):
    "Apply a TSP algorithm to cities, plot the resulting tour, and print information."
    # Find the solution and time how long it takes
    t0 = time.clock()
    tour = algorithm(cities)
    t1 = time.clock()
    assert valid_tour(tour, cities)
    plot_tour(tour); plt.show()
    print("{} city tour with length {:.1f} in {:.3f} secs for {}"
          .format(len(tour), tour_length(tour), t1 - t0, algorithm.__name__))
    
def valid_tour(tour, cities):
    "Is tour a valid tour for these cities?"
    return set(tour) == set(cities) and len(tour) == len(cities)
plot_tsp(alltours_tsp, Cities(8))
```

**This is the error im getting:**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [23], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 plot_tsp(alltours_tsp, Cities(8))

Input In [22], in plot_tsp(algorithm, cities)
      6 t1 = time.perf_counter()
      7 assert valid_tour(tour, cities)
----> 8 plot_tour(tour); plt.show()
      9 print("{} city tour with length {:.1f} in {:.3f} secs for {}"
     10       .format(len(tour), tour_length(tour), t1 - t0, algorithm.__name__))

Input In [17], in plot_tour(tour)
      1 def plot_tour(tour): 
      2     "Plot the cities as circles and the tour as lines between them."
----> 3     plot_lines(list(tour) + [tour[0]])

Input In [17], in plot_lines(points, style)
      5 def plot_lines(points, style='bo-'):
      6     "Plot lines to connect a series of points."
----> 7     plt.plot(map(X, points), map(Y, points), style)
      8     plt.axis('scaled'); plt.axis('off')

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py:2757, in plot(scalex, scaley, data, *args, **kwargs)
   2755 @_copy_docstring_and_deprecators(Axes.plot)
   2756 def plot(*args, scalex=True, scaley=True, data=None, **kwargs):
-> 2757     return gca().plot(
   2758         *args, scalex=scalex, scaley=scaley,
   2759         **({"data": data} if data is not None else {}), **kwargs)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py:1632, in Axes.plot(self, scalex, scaley, data, *args, **kwargs)
   1390 """
   1391 Plot y versus x as lines and/or markers.
   1392 
   (...)
   1629 (``'green'``) or hex strings (``'#008000'``).
   1630 """
   1631 kwargs = cbook.normalize_kwargs(kwargs, mlines.Line2D)
-> 1632 lines = [*self._get_lines(*args, data=data, **kwargs)]
   1633 for line in lines:
   1634     self.add_line(line)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py:312, in _process_plot_var_args.__call__(self, data, *args, **kwargs)
    310     this += args[0],
    311     args = args[1:]
--> 312 yield from self._plot_args(this, kwargs)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py:493, in _process_plot_var_args._plot_args(self, tup, kwargs, return_kwargs)
    490     x, y = index_of(xy[-1])
    492 if self.axes.xaxis is not None:
--> 493     self.axes.xaxis.update_units(x)
    494 if self.axes.yaxis is not None:
    495     self.axes.yaxis.update_units(y)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py:1443, in Axis.update_units(self, data)
   1437 def update_units(self, data):
   1438     """
   1439     Introspect *data* for units converter and update the
   1440     axis.converter instance if necessary. Return *True*
   1441     if *data* is registered for unit conversion.
   1442     """
-> 1443     converter = munits.registry.get_converter(data)
   1444     if converter is None:
   1445         return False

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\units.py:206, in Registry.get_converter(self, x)
    202 else:
    203     # ... and avoid infinite recursion for pathological iterables for
    204     # which indexing returns instances of the same iterable class.
    205     if type(first) is not type(x):
--> 206         return self.get_converter(first)
    207 return None

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\units.py:199, in Registry.get_converter(self, x)
    197         pass
    198 try:  # If cache lookup fails, look up based on first element...
--> 199     first = cbook.safe_first_element(x)
    200 except (TypeError, StopIteration):
    201     pass

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py:1678, in safe_first_element(obj)
   1676     except TypeError:
   1677         pass
-> 1678     raise RuntimeError("matplotlib does not support generators "
   1679                        "as input")
   1680 return next(iter(obj))

RuntimeError: matplotlib does not support generators as input
```

Comment: Just put a call to `list(...)` around the `map()`, to turn the generator into an explicit list.

Comment: hello @jasonharper ,  thank you for your fast response.  yes, I call `plt.plot(list(map(X, points)), list(map(Y, points)), style)`. but after running the code `plot_tour(alltours_tsp(Cities(8)))` the error is gone but it doesn't seem to be outputting any graph or plot. is there another reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this notebook was made for an earlier version of python and packages. That's why you're having so many problems. I recommend tracking down some specifications of what python and package versions were used in the course. However, I did get a lot of the notebook to run with these changes:

```py
def plot_lines(points, style='bo-'):
    "Plot lines to connect a series of points."
    plt.plot(list(map(X, points)), list(map(Y, points)), style)
    plt.axis('scaled'); plt.axis('off')
```

Later on, `time.time()` should be replaced with `perf_counter()`.

```py
def plot_tsp(algorithm, cities):
    "Apply a TSP algorithm to cities, plot the resulting tour, and print information."
    # Find the solution and time how long it takes
    t0 = time.perf_counter()
    tour = algorithm(cities)
    t1 = time.perf_counter()
    assert valid_tour(tour, cities)
    plot_tour(tour); plt.show()
    print("{} city tour with length {:.1f} in {:.3f} secs for {}"
          .format(len(tour), tour_length(tour), t1 - t0, algorithm.__name__))
```

```py
def benchmark(function, inputs):
    "Run function on all the inputs; return pair of (average_time_taken, results)."
    t0           = time.perf_counter()
    results      = map(function, inputs)
    t1           = time.perf_counter()
    average_time = (t1 - t0) / len(inputs)
    return (average_time, results)
```

There are other changes that have to be made further down the notebook, however. I had problems with the `benchmark` function and the `USA big map` url request. You should really consider digging the package versions though.

Comment: hello @K.Cl, thank you for your response. yes, Ive already changed it to `plt.plot(list(map(X, points)), list(map(Y, points)), style)`. but after running the next code to display the plot, `plot_tour(alltours_tsp(Cities(8)))` , it doesn't seem to be outputting any graph or plot. is there a reason for this?

Comment: Since that's your first plot in the notebook, consider adding this after plot_tour. `plt.show()`, or add this `%matplotlib inline` to the beginning of the cell, just once.